# does multiple shard key helps performance in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Since sharding database use shard key to split chunk AND route queries, so I think maybe more shard key can helps to make more queries targeted

I tried to specify multiple keys like this

```
db.runCommand( { shardcollection : "test.users" , key : {_id:1, email : 1 ,address:1}
```

but I have no idea if it works and what the downsides of doing this

Comment: I tried to explain ,but seems no luck ...  only shard key one can work as route index ,the others seems no effect on querying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clear here, you can only have one shard key. So you cannot have *multiple shard keys*.

However, you are suggesting a [compound index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeysIndexes) as the shard key. This can be done, but there are some limitations.

For example the combination of `_id`, `email` and `address` must be unique.

Documents for [choosing a shard key](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Choosing+a+Shard+Key). There are several more considerations that I cannot list here. Please see that document.

Answer (score 3):

Selection of shard key based on :

```
{coarseLocality : 1, search : 1}
```

coarseLocality is whatever locality you want for your data,
search is a common search on your data.

You must have an index on the key you shard by, so if you choose a randomly-valued
key that you don’t query by, you’re basically wasting an index. Every additional index
makes writes slower, so it’s important to keep the number of indexes as low as possible.

So,increasing shard key combination doesn't help much.

Extract taken from Kristina Chodrow's book "Scaling MongoDB".